# Spotfire - Getting data from one table that falls between two dates in another table and adding to a calculated column

Tags: sql, calculated-columns, spotfire

What would be the expression to create a calculated column in Table Example 2 called "SZODMAXCALC", that would contain the SZODMAXCALC from Table Example 1 given that the data from Table Example 1 falls between the dates (DTTMSTART and DTTMEND) within Table Example 2?

Maybe this is easier done on the SQL side that loads the data?

[image: Table Example]

Comment: I dont get the logic for SZODMAXCALC in table 1 and it seems important to create logic for table 2.

Comment: I just made this to show for an example.

Comment: Do you know what is the logic for desired column data in table 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to create a calculated column that references a column in another table.

you will need to do a join either in Spotfire (via [Insert...Columns](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/add/add_how_to_insert_columns_from_external_data.htm))* or on the SQL-side of things (either via a view on your database or by creating a new information link in Spotfire).

the best method depends on your data structure, implementation, and desired results, so I'm not able to recommed there. take a look at both options and evaluate which one works best.

---

* **NOTE** that Spotfire cannot join based on a Calculated Column as a common key. that is, using your example, if `[WELLNAME]` is a calculated column, you **cannot** tell Spotfire the equivalent of `SELECT wellname, ... FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.wellname = table_b.wellname`.

the alternative is to Insert...Transformation and choose **Insert New Calculated Column**, and to join on that instead.

the reason for this is that calculated columns are very mutable; they could change frequently based on a user action. it would be inefficient to re-execute the join each time the column's contents changed. conversely, a "Transformation Calculated Column" is only updated when the data table is loaded.